# Best way to update the same column without using x update statements (if possible)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a few questions regarding the following scenario -

Consider this table (db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7fa1c4ea50dae96d69c10241d0547020)):

```
create TABLE StudentClass( 
name [nvarchar](30) NULL,
class [nvarchar](100) NULL,
)

insert into StudentClass
values ('Anne', 'Math;Art;Art History'),
('Bill', 'Math;English'),
('Charlie', 'English'),
('Daisy', 'English;Art;Art History'),
('Eddy', 'Math;Art')
```

I want to replace each class subject with a number code. For example:

```
Math --> 001
English --> 002
Art --> 003
Art History --> 004
```

If I try to do this in one update statement, it won't let me do that. The only thing I could think of was four separate statements using replace:

```
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'Math', '001')
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'English', '002')
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'Art', '003')
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'Art History', '004')
```

This *almost* works, but not quite. Since "Art History" contains "Art" in it, this update `update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'Art', '003')` triggers first and messes up the next update.

My 2 questions are:

First, is there a better way to update the same column instead of making x update statements?

And second, is there a better way to make sure that the Art/ArtHistory replacement doesn't happen? For this, the only thing I could think of was switching the query order so that it looks like this, but I assume there's a better way I don't know about:

```
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'Math', '001')
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'English', '002')
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'Art History', '004')
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'Art', '003')
```

Appreciate all the help as always!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @PhilCoulson I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 :)

Comment: The "best" way is to properly normalize your table and NOT store delimited values in a single column. But given that this can only be a one-time process, why do you need anything "better"?

Comment: @SMor - you’re right that this is a one-time process. I mainly asked just for the sake of curiosity :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases you will probably have a table with the information about the numbers of the classes

In this case you can use JOIN in order to get the result that you need without manually write the names of the options in your query.

With that being said, using small number of consist list of classes numbers and if you do not have that information in table you can use simply CASE statement. THIS MEAN THAT YOU COUNT ON THE ORDER OF THE OPTIONS (when... Then...) in the CASE  STATEMENT. This option in this specific scenario is better since you do not need to parse the content of the text.

If you need more flexiblke solution then you can use something like bellow (which will cost more since we parse the content of the text (split it and aggregate) but provide more flexible solution which might fit your needs

```
;With MyCTE AS (
    SELECT s.name, s.class, V.Num
    FROM StudentClass s
    CROSS APPLY string_split(s.class, ';') ca
    LEFT JOIN (VALUES (N'Math', '001'), (N'English', '002'),(N'Art', '003'),(N'Art History', '004')) V  (Class, Num) ON V.Class = ca.value
) 
SELECT [name], class, STRING_AGG(Num, ';')
FROM MyCTE
GROUP BY [name], class
```

Note! since I do not have table, I am using this part `(VALUES (N'Math', '001'), (N'English', '002'),(N'Art', '003'),(N'Art History', '004')) V  (Class, Num)`  in order to have the values in tabular structure on the fly

Answer (score 2):

Please, please, PLEASE don't store multiple values in one columns. Add a one-to-many table of person to class.  Then you can find all people in Art class without having to to a "contains" and worrying about Art History as well.

Then, use a primary key on each table that has no meaning outside of the table (e.g. don't use "name" as the class key. Then, you can link students to classes and have *multiple* columns for classes (name, code, etc.) that you can join to students however you want to.

In short, you're trying to solve a problem that you shouldn't have in the first place...

Comment: This is the only truly correct answer. It doesn't "solve" the problem because the problem exists in the first place because the design of the table is flawed. If they fix the design problem the update is suddenly painless and the need for this question would disappear.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense to me! Unfortunately, I was working with exported data which came in this format, so I didn’t get to design the table. This is mainly why I was trying to think of best solutions given the design constraint :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach this, which is VERY similar to Ronan's solution posted before me). Just that I am using a CTE instead of value constructor and have an `update` statement, which I assumed to be part of your question.

```
with cte (class, label) as

(select 'Math', '001' union all
 select 'English', '002' union all
 select 'Art', '003' union all
 select 'Art History', '004'),

cte2 as
(select t1.name, t1.class, string_agg(t3.label,';') as new_class
 from StudentClass t1
 cross apply string_split(t1.class,';') as t2
 left join cte t3 on t3.class=t2.value
 group by t1.name, t1.class)

update a
set a.class=b.new_class
from StudentClass a 
join cte2 b on a.name=b.name;
```

**Breakdown of steps:**

- Define a small update lookup using a `CTE`.
- Use `string_split` to
  split delimited values into rows and use `cross apply` to laterally
  append them to the dataset.
- Use a `left join` to pull the right
  update value based on the lookup.
- Use `string_agg` to aggregate the
  values.
- Update your main table by joining back to the final `CTE`

You should really consider stopping at that `join` after `string_split` and not stitch it back together with `string_agg`. It's rarely a good idea to use delimited strings to store multiple values. I understand if you don't have the liberty to change the table design.

Comment: This is the exact solution which I published 10 minutes before you `:-)`  (you used another CTE instead of VALUES but this is exact same solution of using string_agg on the result of string_split)

Comment: @RonenAriely I was still typing and only saw your answer once I posted it.

Comment: This make sense @PhilCoulson and it happens to us all from time to time :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
update StudentClass set class = 
CASE 
  WHEN class LIKE '%Math%' THEN replace(class, 'Math', '001')
  WHEN class LIKE '%English%' THEN replace(class, 'English', '002')
  WHEN class LIKE '%Art History%' THEN replace(class, 'Art History', '004')
  WHEN class LIKE '%Art%' THEN replace(class, 'Art', '003')
  ELSE '000' 
END;
```

If there are more than one true WHEN condition, you must the more lenght condition before the short one!
CASE statement Jump the firs true!

In the question is this updates bad order:

```
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'Art', '003')
update StudentClass set class = replace(class, 'Art History', '004')
```

Because before second update there isn't any 'Art History' just '003 History'!

Comment: Your numerical values should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: I thought about using some kind of case statement, but it doesn't work because it'll only update the value if it's an exact match. For example, using what you wrote will give Charlie as 002, but everyone else will be 000

Comment: @razzberry you can you `like` in `case` just the same as `=`.

Comment: I Updated it with like

Comment: An obvious problem with this suggestion is that '%Art% will match anything that '%Art History%' will match - resulting in incorrect translation for singleton values. And it doesn't work at all for multi-valued strings. Pity or sympathy upvotes don't help. Downvotes are not "punishment".

Comment: Hi! I updated my answer, i haven't enough time to read about CASE statement, just now. So I wrote an partial answer (with that exception), perhaps razberry can read about that. I think downvote is a punishment, not other, because of -2 reputation. But this button has sence, if the answer is very bad (not exact when have to use / i think nobody can make exact rule). You can check this answer is 'more worst' then other. I dont think my answer is bad. Perhaps the main reason can be that I don't test it. It is? Is all answer tested? Thank you for the answer. Have a nice day guys!